# I made a withdraw from my crypto wallet to extern wallet. After few days they haven’t got the transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, withdrawal

I have triple checked address, it is the right one. I used BTC chain. My crypto.com says that transaction was complete. What is wrong? Why they haven’t got the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the external wallet is synchronized with the network? If you want someone to help investigate further, you may need to reveal more details such as what software the external wallet is, and perhaps the address you were trying to pay.—Also, you tagged this question with [bitcoin-cash](/questions/tagged/bitcoin-cash), but you are saying that you used the BTC chain. Bitcoin Cash (BCH) is an altcoin that has its own blockchain and network, so if your external wallet is a Bitcoin Cash wallet that would be an explanation for you not seeing the transaction.

Comment: Maybe he made a mistake and didn't want to tag bitcoin cash?

Comment: I guess we'll never know, because they never returned to follow up.